# How to revoke Google Nearby permissions for an app?

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-bluetooth, google-nearby, google-nearby-messages

The first time I tried to test the Google Nearby API, I saw an "Allow  to use Nearby" dialog which prompted for permission and this dialog mentioned that this setting could be changed later from **Settings > Google > Nearby**. However this location does not seem to exist on the app. I do see **Settings > Google** but there is no **Nearby** under the Google settings (tried on both device and emulator).

I also found the same information online at https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6260286?hl=en but this seems incorrect based on the settings I actually see.

Does anyone know how to disable the Nearby permission (because I want to be able to test this again and it doesn't seem possible to revoke this once granted)?

Thanks!

Comment: under Setting>Google>Set up & restore option, where you may find an option to disable nearby permission

Comment: check this link, it might help you [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36511317/is-it-possible-to-grant-nearby-api-permissions-from-phone-settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36511317/is-it-possible-to-grant-nearby-api-permissions-from-phone-settings?noredirect=1&lq=1)